# Browserify can't find local module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gruntjs, browserify

I have same issue but with local component.

That's my tree:

```
app
|
 - assets
  |
   - js
    |
     - app.jsx
    |
     - MainComponent.jsx
```

But when I run command:

`macpro:app user$ browserify assets/js/app.jsx > tesapp.js`

It response error :

> Error: Cannot find module 'MainComponent' from
>   '/Users/user/WebstormProjects/gowithme/app/assets/js'

That is code of app.jsx file :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM =  require('react-dom');
var  MainComponent  = require('MainComponent');
console.log("Test",MainComponent);
```

Comment: You need to use local paths when using local modules, like: `require('../../MainComponent')`. Absolute paths are used to fetch `node_modules` modules.

Comment: It is not node module, and MainComponet is on the same level with app.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you are using `.jsx` extension. By default browserify cannot recognize unknown extension. Add `browserifyOptions` to you grunt config, it might help:

```
options: {
    transform: [['babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}]],
    browserifyOptions: {
        debug: true,
        extensions: ['.jsx']
    }
}
```

Also I suggest to omit usage of `.jsx`. **[No .jsx extension?](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/87#issuecomment-234627904)**

Comment: Thanks dude you save my time. I didn't had any idea of how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the relative path when you're loading a local module (i.e. a `.js` file of your own) with `require`:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM =  require('react-dom');
var  MainComponent  = require('./MainComponent'); //added ./ so now the path is relative
console.log("Test",MainComponent);
```

When using an absolute path (like `require('fs')` or `require('react')`) node will try to load native modules (like `fs`, `path` etc) or modules inside `node_modules`.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules

Comment: Same issue with ./   Error: Cannot find module './MainComponent' from /Users/user/WebstormProjects/gowithme/app/assets/js